# Is there a method, tool, xslt that would show the net results of the B2C XML inheritance?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

For example, what would the net result of the inheritance be for:

- TrustFrameworkBase
- TrustFrameworkExtension
- SignUpSignin

--> resultant XML processed by B2C?

Ideally there would be something like the Resultant Set of Policies for Active Directory Group Policies if you're familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

None that I'm aware of but basically top policies elements replace lower (base policies) ones.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding WinMerge (opensource @ https://winmerge.org/) and OSO XML Merge (https://osocorporation.com/xmlmerge).